# Error al listar datos de un array

Tags: php

Intento listar solo los símbolos (`symbol`) de un array y tengo este error:

> Warning: foreach() argument must be of type array|object, string given in

Array (Instruments)

```
{
"status":"OK",
"instruments":[{
  "instrumentId":{
    "marketId":"ROFX",
    "symbol":"TRI.ROS/DIC23 352 C"
    },
    "cficode":"OCAFXS"
  },
  {
  "instrumentId":{
     "marketId":"ROFX",
     "symbol":"MERV - XMEV - AGRO - 48hs"},
     "cficode":"ESXXXX"
   },
   {
   "instrumentId":{
      "marketId":"ROFX",
      "symbol":"TRI.ROS/ENE23 264 P"
   },
     "cficode":"OPAFXS"
   }...
```

PHP

```
<?php

$instruments = $data->getmarketdata('https://api.remarkets.primary.com.ar/rest/instruments/all');

$explode = explode(",", $instruments);

if(is_array($explode) || is_object($explode)){
    foreach($explode[2] as $row){
        echo $row['symbol'];
    }
}

?>
```

Agradezco la ayuda de antemano

Answer (score 2):

Eso no es un array, es un string en formato json que debes decodificar con `json_decode`, el cual te devolverá un objeto que tiene la propiedad `instruments` que contiene a su vez un array de objetos, y que luego puedes recorrer de este modo para obtener la propiedad de objeto `symbol` de cada uno de ellos:

```
<?php

$instruments = $data->getmarketdata('https://api.remarkets.primary.com.ar/rest/instruments/all');

$datos = json_decode($instruments);

foreach ($datos->instruments as $instrumento) {
    echo $instrumento->instrumentId->symbol;
}
```

Prueba y nos cuentas.

Comment: Gracias MasterGuru, voy a probarlo entonces... gracias nuevamente!